# type.FindMembers missing inherited private members with binding flags

Tags: c#, .net

EDIT: I had an error in my unit test. So my question is invalid. I have marked the correct answer below and the question should be "How do I get private members on inherited classes".

I traverse the class hierarchy to get the private members I need.

I am using reflection to get the members of a class hierarchy. Originally, I was pulling properties and fields separately. I refactored my code just to get `MemberInfo` and started running into a small issue.

Originally I was able to get all the fields using:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

This would return all public and private fields in the class hierarchy.
For example on the classes:

```
     class ViewModel {

            [MetaData("MetaFieldType1", typeof(Parent), null)]
            public string field1;

            [MetaData("MetaFieldType2", typeof(Parent), "Field Value 2")]
            private string field2;

            [MetaData("MetaProtectedField", typeof(Parent), "Protected Field")]
            protected string pField;

            protected string pField2;

            [MetaData("MetaType 1", typeof(Parent), null)]
            public String Prop1 { get; set; }
            [MetaData("MetaType 2", typeof(Parent), "The Value")]
            public String Prop2 { get; set; }

            public string Field2 { get { return field2; } set { field2 = value; } }
        }

        class ViewModel2 : ViewModel {

            public string PField { get { return pField; } set { pField = value; } }

            [MetaData("MetaProtectedField2", typeof(Parent), null)]
            public string PField2 { get { return pField2; } set { pField2 = value; } }
        }
```

4 fields would be returned on both `ViewModel` and `ViewModel2`

I then changed the code to use (rather than getting properties then fields):

```
type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Property,
                BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                allMemberFilter,null)
```

Where

```
protected static readonly MemberFilter allMemberFilter = new MemberFilter(
            delegate (MemberInfo objMemberInfo, Object objSearch) {
                return true;
            });
```

and `ViewModel` returns all the properties and fields; however, `ViewModel2` is missing the private fields (i.e. `field2`) found in `ViewModel`. This was not the case when getting them using the `GetFields` and `GetProperties` with the same binding flags.

If I change `field2` to protected, then it shows up in the search.

Is this an issue with the framework or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know the exact definitions of `member` and `field`, but I'm pretty sure that a private `field` of a base class is not a `member` of the inheriting class.

Comment: Are you sure that `typeof (ViewModel2).GetFields(...` returns 4 items? I tested this and it returned 3 items.

Comment: @YacoubMassad You are correct, I had an error in my unit tests giving me the error. If I want the private members from an inherited class, I'm going to have to traverse the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, private members of a base `Type` are considered members of the inherited `Type`. from *C# Language Specification Version 5.0*:

> A class inherits the members of its base class. Inheritance means that a class implicitly ***contains all members of its base class*** *(A.k.a: Including the private members of the base class)*, except for the instance and static constructors, and the destructors of the base class.

If you inspect the `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` documentation, you will see it refers only to `static` members:

> Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned.

With that said, apparently, and unfortunately the only way to get `private` members of a `Type` is using reflection on their declaring `Type`, which means, in our case - the base `Type` itself.

So we will have to write an extension to do so recursively:

```
static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllInstanceMembers(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null || type == typeof (object) || !type.IsClass || type.IsInterface)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<MemberInfo>();
        }

        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> baseMembers = type.BaseType.GetAllInstanceMembers();

        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> interfacesMembers = type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetAllInstanceMembers());

        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> currentMembers = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Property,
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            AllMemberFilter, null);

        return baseMembers.Concat(interfacesMembers).Concat(currentMembers);
    }

    static readonly MemberFilter AllMemberFilter = (objMemberInfo, objSearch) => true;
}
```

Note that apparently `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` makes the method return the *backing fields* generated by the constructor for the *auto-properties* while in the question's example they are not returned, this can be fixed by changing the `return` line to:

```
return baseMembers.Concat(interfacesMembers).Concat(currentMembers)
    .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null);
```

Also, I must say that I am getting the same results for `GetMembers`, `FindMembers` and `GetProperties`/`GetFields`

Comment: After realizing an error in my unit test, I came up with a similar solution. I use the original query to get all the public/private/protected members I need in the type. Then I recursively call type.BaseType on the object until it is an instance of object to get the private fields I would need. For my actual use case, I would never really expect to have to do this. So I have it in a separate method just for those rare occurrences.

Comment: Down voter please elaborate so I can improve my answer.